# Postgresql: Extracting substring after first instance of delimiter

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to extract everything after the first instance of a delimiter.
For example:

```
01443-30413 -> 30413
1221-935-5801 -> 935-5801
```

I have tried the following queries:

```
select regexp_replace(car_id, E'-.*', '') from schema.table_name;
select reverse(split_part(reverse(car_id), '-', 1)) from schema.table_name;
```

However both of them return:

- `01443-30413` -> `30413`
- `1221-935-5801` -> `5801`

So it's not working if delimiter appears multiple times.

I'm using Postgresql 11. I come from a MySQL background where you can do:

`select SUBSTRING(car_id FROM (LOCATE('-',car_id)+1)) from table_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do the PG equivalent of your MySQL approach and substring it?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('abcdef-ghi' FROM POSITION('-' in 'abcdef-ghi') + 1)
```

If you don't like the "from" and "in" way of writing arguments, PG also has "normal" comma separated functions:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('abcdef-ghi', STRPOS('abcdef-ghi', '-') + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `regexp_replace` is appropriate, but using the correct pattern:

```
select regexp_replace('1221-935-5801', E'^[^-]+-', '');

935-5801
```

The regex pattern `^[^-]+-` matches, from the start of the string, one or more non dash characters, ending with a dash.  It then replaces with empty string, effectively removing this content.

Note that this approach also works if the input has no dashes at all, in which case it would just return the original input.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regexp pattern :

```
select regexp_replace('1221-935-5801', E'^[^-]+-', '') from schema.table_name
```

Regexp explanation :

- `^` is the beginning of the string
- `[^-]+` means at least one character different than `-`
- ...until the `-` character is met

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in a conventional way in general what we do (found 
 something similar to instr as strpos in postgrsql .) Can try the below

```
    SELECT
     SUBSTR(car_id,strpos(car_id,'-')+1,
     length(car_id) ) from table ;
```